# Python: Finding Unique Subsequences of Unique Strings

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, subsequence

Edit: To the people that downvoted: I was perfectly clear that I did not want code and that I had already tried it myself. All I was looking for was an explanation of what mathematical process yielded the sample results.

First question. I have done a lot of research and finally resorted to asking, so if I missed the answer somewhere I apologize. I have a problem I am really struggling with:

> Write a Python 3 script that takes three command line arguments: 
> 1. The name of a text file that contains n strings separated
>   by white spaces. 
> 2. A positive integer k. 
> 3. The name of a
>   text file that the script will create in order to store all possible
>   subsequences of k unique strings out of the n strings from the input
>   file, one subsequence per line. 
> For example, assume the
>   command line is gen.py input.txt 3 output.txt and the file input.txt
>   contains the following line: 
> Python Java C++ Java Java Python
>   
> Then the program should create the file output.txt containing
>   the following lines (in any order): 
> Python Java C++ 
> Python
>   C++ Java 
> Java C++ Python 
> C++ Java Python 
> The
>   combinations should be generated with your implementation of a
>   generator function (i.e. using the keyword yield).

From my understanding, based on the sample output this doesn't quite follow the definition of a subsequence; nor are they quite permutations, so I'm at a loss for how to go about this. I know how to do the file IO and command line argument portions, I just can't get the right subsequences. I don't need a direct answer as I am supposed to solve this, but if someone could give me some helpful insight it would be much appreciated.

Comment: In the example output, why aren't `Java Python C++` and `C++ Python Java` present?

Comment: That is sort of the source of my problem: I could easily write code that produces those 2 strings with the 4 in the sample output above. I believe those 2 are not included because of the order of the original string. Because there is no subsequence with "Python" in the middle.

Comment: I'm assuming you can't use `itertools.combinations` to do this for you, but that's how you'd do this....

Comment: @AdamSmith: I initially thought of using `itertools` as well, but it doesn't actually apply here due to the above comments: the result is not all permutations, but rather something that involves the sequence of the words in the input.

Comment: @m7mansfield: you should start by writing some code.  Post it here if you get stuck.

Comment: @JohnZwinck combinations respects the sequence of words. `[' '.join(combo for combo in itertools.combinations(txt.split(), 3) if len(set(combo)) == 3]` is the solution

Comment: Well my original code uses the itertools.permutations but this isn't truly a combinatorics problem, it's some sort of half-permutation half-subsequence solution. So it's not quite that simple but thank you.

Comment: @JohnZwick I do have some code already but it doesn't work, it produces the 2 extra strings from your first comment.

Comment: Well, @AdamSmith has basically given you the solution now (in a pretty slick way if I may say so).  I see a career in management in your future.

Comment: @JohnZwinck there's actually a typo in the solution in my comment. I've fixed it in my answer, but since the instructor says they must re-implement `combinations`, this won't satisfy the instructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're allowed to use itertools:

```
import itertools
import sys

def unique_substrings(txt_lst:list, k:int) -> set:
    return set([' '.join(combo) for combo in itertools.combinations(txt_lst, 3) \
                if len(set(combo))==3])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    infile, k, outfile = sys.argv[1:]
    with open(infile) as inf:
        txt_lst = infile.read().split()
    with open(outfile) as outf:
        for line in unique_substrings(txt_lst, k):
            outf.write(line + "\n")
```

However from your instructor's comment:

> The combinations should be generated with your implementation of a generator function (i.e. using the keyword yield).

It doesn't look like that's actually going to work.

`itertools.combinations` could be re-implemented with something approximating the following [(from the docs)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
def combinations(iterable, r):
    # combinations('ABCD', 2) --> AB AC AD BC BD CD
    # combinations(range(4), 3) --> 012 013 023 123
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    if r > n:
        return
    indices = list(range(r))
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
    while True:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            if indices[i] != i + n - r:
                break
        else:
            return
        indices[i] += 1
        for j in range(i+1, r):
            indices[j] = indices[j-1] + 1
        yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I am still confused. I thought his sample output wasn't a combination or permutation? Because both sets of solutions to those do not satisfy the sample output, so would you be able to explain your solution?

Comment: Well I thought it was some sort of modified permutation because order matters, doesn't it? I know your solution works I'm just trying to understand.

Comment: @m7mansfield order matters in combinations. `combinations([0,1,2,3], 3)` is all 3-length permutations where order is respected e.g. `012 013 023 123`

Comment: Ah I follow. Well clearly I need to study up on my combinatorics. Thanks again for the help!